# Mostrar errores en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.4 no muestra los errores, solo sale error 500 cuando falla algo. ¿Cómo hago para que en vez de estar apareciéndome los errores 500 me diga en qué parte está el error? He hecho de todo y no logro, no sé qué le habrán metido que sale eso.

Comment: puedes comentar un poco que pasos dices que has hecho?

Comment: Hola Chris, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] y leas [ask] para mejorar tus publicaciones. He editado la pregunta para quitar palabras malsonantes y corregir la ortografía.

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, se resuelve con esto:
sudo chmod -R gu+w storage
sudo chmod -R gu0+w storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que tenga el mismpo problema, se resuelve con esto:

```
sudo chmod -R gu+w storage
sudo chmod -R guo+w storage
```